# A sequence of coin tosses HTTHT...can be related to the sequence 10010...

Tags: probability

> A sequence of coin tosses HTTHT...can be related to the sequence
>   10010...and used to generate random binary numbers. If an unbiased coin is tossed 9 times and the related sequence of 0's and 1's is
>   recorded, what is the probability that the binary number will exceed
>   256?

I'm a little confused on how to set up the math for the problem - I know that 256 in binary is 100000000, and to calculate the probability that it will exceed 256 you want to know the probability of getting every number *above* 256 but...how do I find that out exactly? And what do I do with that information?

Comment: What is the maximum value of a 9 bit binary number if the leading bit is a 0?

Comment: @JohnDouma that would be 255

Comment: So, what do you think about the probability of getting more than 256? By the way, do you want the probability of getting greater than or the probability of getting greater than or equal?

Comment: @JohnDouma it's my understand that you don't want 256, only numbers greater than 256 - I'd assume the probability of getting anything bigger than 256 would just be 1 minus the probability of getting 256, but I don't see how to actually calculate the probability of 256...

Comment: No. The probability of getting 256 or any other specific number is $\frac{1}{512}$. Can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a first 0 the maximum you can get is $(011111111)_{2}=255$

To exceed 256 you have to get something like $(100000100)_{2}$, i.e. get the first 1, and do not get all zero for the 8 tosses after that.

The probability is then $\tfrac{1}{2}\times(1-(\tfrac{1}{2})^8)$

Comment: So just so I understand - the first 1/2 that you're multiplying by is the chance to get a 1 - and the "1-$(1/2)^8$" is the probability of NOT getting all tails on the remaining throws?

Comment: @Tai M. Yes, that is correct.